# Should I upgrade my Huawei HG8245 router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have Huawei HG8245 router in my office, specs can be found [here](https://combasst.en.alibaba.com/product/1479042600-802645697/HUAWEI_HG8245_ONT_Optical_Network_Terminal.html). From time to time, some Wi-Fi connections drop, meantime two guys using Ethernet don't have any issues. I can't tell whether it's a router problem or not, maybe it's just not suited to handle so many connections: 10-15 people on wi-fi + probably everyone has a connected smartphone.

Should I buy a more powerful router? How can I learn from the specs about the max or recommended # of connected devices?

Comment: You probably won't be able to. You would need more specific information about the hardware. As it has only 8W power draw on average it could be the case that it can't handle the load. Does it get really warm (physically)?

Comment: @Seth yes, it's a bit warm. What kind of information do you need? The full official specs can be found [here](http://e.huawei.com/us/marketing-material/onLineView?MaterialID={7D271109-BB63-45E1-AE78-A4C991EB2179}) amonth other models. By upgrading I mean if I should buy a more powerful router.

Comment: Those specs are way better readable. If I didn't misclick, [this should be a direct link](http://e-file.huawei.com/mediafiles/MarketingMaterial/EBG/en/cache/2e418672-cb7e-4dcb-94e4-8c629e4d3066/2e418672-cb7e-4dcb-94e4-8c629e4d3066_22_12.jpeg). B/G/N, 2x2 MIMO with 2 dBi. It doesn't have any information on CPU/RAM as depending on what your devices are doing it might be important. I'm not really sure whenever an upgrade would make sense or not. Warmth certainly is subjective and depends on the device. If it is noticeably warmer (hot) than your hand it might indicate a high load.